# How to change response port in nginx

Tags: nginx

I configured nginx to run on port 85, but is giving response on port 80. I have changed the port to 85 from 80 port. How to change the response to 85 port?

Comment: Could you be more clear and specific?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `listen` directive inside your `server` block reads like:

```
server {
    listen 85 default_server;
}
```

and that your configuration is saved correctly (the `default_server` directive may or may not be required, depending on your configuration). Check that you any other configuration files present to ensure they're correct (such as the default server blocks in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` on Linux distros).

Test your Nginx configuration with `nginx -t` (likely needs to be run as root) and then ensure you restart or reload your Nginx configuration - this will be platform dependent.

All that said, you may want to reconsider using a non-standard port for HTTP.